# Is `SecAction` order important for an OWASP ModSecurity config file?

Tags: web-application, configuration, owasp, nginx, mod-security

Using a web server with Nginx + ModSecurity + OWASP ModSecurity Core Rules...

On the OWASP config file `crs-setup.conf` is the order of the config section `SecAction` important or can i order them differently from the example config file?

Example:

```
SecAction \
 "id:900250,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:'tx.restricted_headers=/proxy/ /lock-token/ /content-range/ /translate/ /if/'"

SecAction \
 "id:900200,\
  phase:1,\
  nolog,\
  pass,\
  t:none,\
  setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS'"
```

By default `SecAction id:900200` is written before `SecAction id:900250`, is that order important?

Comment: Apparently the rules can be in any order on the crs-setup.conf...

Comment: Yes, the order is important. Rules will evaluated where they are defined (grouped by the phases). In the example above the rule 900250 will evaluated before 900200 (before they are in phase:1).

Answer (score 0):

The number is not important. Import the include order of the rules in your web service and the phase that is executed, this will determine the order in which the rules will be executed.

In the case of "SecAction" it should always be "phase:1" and if for example you have a rules file with only SecActions in your web service or in VirtualHost (Apache, I don't know how it is in nginx) of your hosting it should be included before other rule sets like CRS for example